# Supervisord not starting due to dot (.) in directory command

Tags: supervisord

I'm trying to set up supervisor, but am struggling to get it to work.
I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '/home/username/projects/myproject-1'` error when trying to start:

```
[2021-03-09 10:57:00 +0000] [197792] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-03-09 10:57:00 +0000] [197792] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/username/projects/myproject-1.10/myproject.sock (197792)
[2021-03-09 10:57:00 +0000] [197792] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-03-09 10:57:00 +0000] [197795] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 197795
[2021-03-09 10:57:00 +0000] [197795] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/myproject-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/myproject-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/myproject-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/myproject-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/myproject-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/myproject-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/myproject-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '/home/username/projects/myproject-1'
[2021-03-09 10:57:00 +0000] [197795] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 197795)
[2021-03-09 10:57:00 +0000] [197792] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2021-03-09 10:57:00 +0000] [197792] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

My config file goes as follows:

```
[program:myproject]
directory=/home/username/projects/myproject-1.10
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=username
stderr_logfile=/var/log/myproject.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/myproject.out.log
command=/home/username/.virtualenvs/myproject-3.6/bin/gunicorn --workers 5 --bind unix:/home/username/projects/myproject-1.10/myproject.sock /home/username/projects/myproject-1.10/myproject_project.wsgi:application
```

I tried changing to `directory='/home/username/projects/myproject-1.10'` and `directory="/home/username/projects/myproject-1.10"` (single and double quotes) and rereading/reloading supervisord, to no avail.

As a workaround, I might set the directory in the wsgi I'm calling, but why doesn't supervisor want a dot in a directory name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with supervisord or the directory provided, but rather with the command provided.

`command=/home/username/.virtualenvs/myproject-3.6/bin/gunicorn --workers 5 --bind unix:/home/username/projects/myproject-1.10/myproject.sock /home/username/projects/myproject-1.10/myproject_project.wsgi:application`

The last part shouldn't include a directory; it should be just `myproject_project.wsgi:application`. Dots are seen as directories. The right directory is already set/changed per the supervisord config.